# Откуда появилось имя Чебурашка?

Tags: этимология, литература

В интервью Успенский говорил: *«Я пришел в гости к другу, а его маленькая дочка примеряла пушистую шубу, которая тащилась по полу, Девчонка постоянно падала, запинаясь о шубу. И её отец после очередного падения воскликнул: «Ой, опять чебурахнулась!». Это слово врезалось мне в память, я спросил его значение. Оказалось, что «чебурахнуться» — это значит «упасть». Так и появилось имя моего героя».*
Действительно ли так? И, если да, что это за слово такое — чебурахнуться?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не совсем понял вопрос... Вы о том, что сказал Успенский, или о самом слове?
Одно могу сказать, Успенский несколько раз "менял показания". 
Тут дело такое. Уважаемый Эдуард Николаевич очень трепетно относится к авторским правам на своих героев, неоднократно судился с со всякими детскими больницами и магазинами за незаконное использование его персонажей. Пришлось как-то ему доказывать и право на Чебурашку. В качестве аргумента противоположной стороны было предъявлено раскопанное где-то в Поволжье диалектное "чебурахать", "чебурахнуть" (значение сейчас уже и точно и не скажу, кажется, что-то типа "раскатисто кричать", не "упасть" точно) и производное "чебурашка". Тогда-то и родилась версия о маленькой девочке.

А, вот нашел у Даля.

ЧЕБУРАХАТЬ

ЧЕБУРАХАТЬ, чебурахнуть что, чебурыхнуть, сиб. бросить, кинуть, опрокинуть с громом, грохнуть, шлепнуть; || Чебурахнуть или чебурахнуться, упасть, грянуться, грохнуться, растянуться. Чебурах м. точка чебураха, перечап, точка равновесия, опрокидная точка. Вещь на чебурахе, лежит или стоит на перевесе, чуть тронь, так опрокинется. Ловушки на крыс, на тетеревов делаются на чебурахе. Фигляр ходит по канату на чебурахе.

Но это сибирское значение. А вот дальше есть и поволжское, правда, не совсем то, что я имел в виду:

Чебурак м. волжск. чебурашка ж. чебурок или чебурка, чабурок, кляпыш, шашка бурлацкой лямки, привешенная на хвосте; она захлестывается для тяги за подачу (на судне), или за бечеву (на берегу).

А Успенский явно воспользовался вот этим:

|| Чебурашка, об. ванька-встанька, куколка, которая, как ни кинь ее, сама встает на ноги. Зачебурить чебурок, захлестнуть за бичеву. Чебуткать ребенка, кур. качать на своей ноге.

Answer (score -1):

На Среднем Урале достаточно распространена фамилия Чебурашкины. Явно её носители получили не от Успенского. А вот благодарны они автору несуразного персонажа за "популяризацию" - вряд ли.

Comment: Вопрос был не о благодарности/неблагодарности за ассоциацию с Чебурашкой, а, скорее, об этимологии слова "чебурахнуться".